# What is the subject in "While nestled inside that divine sanctuary"?

Tags: participles

> **While nestled inside that divine sanctuary**, words were my window to the world outside my perch in Columbus, Ohio. ([Benita Porter, The Power of Words](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/4210/))

It seems like *while-clause* is a participial clause (a dangling participial one). Is it? If so, is the subject ‘I’?

Comment: As the son of an English professor I am very happy to see this question! Yes, that is a classic dangling participle (whether it's a clause depends on your theology); it could go in a textbook as a warning to writers. And 'I' **should** govern *nestled*, but, alas, doesn't, because it got left out.

Comment: Technically speaking, ***words*** is the subject. But it's a badly-formed sentence, so if you try to parse it you end up with gibberish.

Comment: I think 'words' is a subject for 'words were my window.' But in the subordinate clause 'while (I was) nestled inside that divine sanctuary,' subject is 'I.'

Comment: It's prescriptively incorrect, but see CGEL pages 610-611 for a descriptive account of when a "dangling participle" is acceptable or not.  For example, the subject of ***said*** in ***"Having said that,*** *it must be admitted that the new plan also has advantages"* is unstated but can be understood from context, so it's generally considered acceptable.  I think you could say the same about your example, but clearly opinions differ.

Comment: @StoneyB: Can you write that as an answer to this question?

Comment: @snailboat: For reasons I can't put my finger on, I find OP's example more glaringly "ungrammatical/awkward" than yours. I think it's to do with that initial ***while***, which slightly distracts me from seamlessly adding the omitted subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. This is a classic dangling participle (past participle in this case). The subject is "words" but the participle isn't meant to modify "words" (at least, I don't *think* the words were nestled anywhere). The clause is *meant* to modify "I" but the author never put "I" into the sentence at all.